# Trouble at creating a decorator in Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-decorators, flask-login

I and making a flask app for appointments. I made a admin page and sudo admin page for different levels of login and different levels of authorities. For the admin section and page access after login I used @login_required decorator:

```
@views.route('/admin-page-contact-list')
@login_required
def admin_page_contact_list():
    contact_enter = ContactForm.query.all()
    return render_template("admin-page-contact-ent.html", contact_form = contact_enter)
```

the above is the sample of the admin page where the admin can see all the contact form entries.

I wanted to do the same for my sudo admin access because i dont want others to access the sudo admin page and create new admins and gain access.

```
def sudo_admin_login_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if not current_user.is_authenticated or not current_user.is_sudo_admin:
            flash('Please contact store authorities for any extra Info!', category='error')
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view
```

I made this decorator and used it where ever i wanted to give access only to sudo admin for example

```
@views.route('/sudo-admin-page-contact-list')
@sudo_admin_login_required
def sudo_admin_page_contact_list():
    return render_template('sudo-admin-page-contact-ent.html')
```

this shows all the contact entries to the sudo admin.

the following is the **init**.py code for login manager

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        sudo_admin = SudoAdminAccount.query.get(int(id))
        if sudo_admin:
            return sudo_admin

        return AdminAccount.query.get(int(id))

    return app
```

```
auth.route('/sudo-admin-login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sudo_admin_login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sudoAdminEmail = request.form.get('sudo-admin-email')
        sudoAdminIdNumber = request.form.get('sudo-admin-id-key')
        sudoAdminPassword = request.form.get('sudo-admin-password')

        sudo_admin = SudoAdminAccount.query.filter_by(sudoAdminEmail = sudoAdminEmail).first()
        if sudo_admin:
            if check_password_hash(sudo_admin.sudoAdminIdKey, sudoAdminIdNumber):
                if check_password_hash(sudo_admin.sudoAdminPassword, sudoAdminPassword):
                    flash('Logged In successfully!', category='success')
                    login_user(sudo_admin, remember = True)
                    return redirect(url_for('views.sudo_admin_page_contact_list'))
                else:
                    flash('Incorrect Password, Try again!', category='error')
            else:
                flash('Incorrect Sudo Admin ID, Try again!', category='error')
        else:
            flash('Email Doesnot Exist!', category='error')

    return render_template("sudo-admin-login.html")
```

the above code is my sudo admin login code.

as soon as i login with the email sudo admin id key and password i get flashed that the login was succcessfull and there is one more flashed msg that says 'Please contact store authorities for any extra Info!' and I get redirected to views.home page but i want it such that if the login is unsuccessful that the user gets redirect to views.home but if it is successful the the sudo admin gets redirected to views.sudo_admin_page_contact_list

After the modification in the **init**.py the login restriction works fine but there is one error. If I login as Admin I can still access the sudo admin access pages

I also tried to create two decorators for each level of login:-

```
def admin_login_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if not current_user.is_authenticated or not isinstance(current_user, AdminAccount):
            flash('Access denied. You must be logged in as an admin.', category='error')
            return redirect(url_for('auth.admin_login'))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view

def sudo_admin_login_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if not current_user.is_authenticated or not isinstance(current_user, SudoAdminAccount) :
            flash('Access denied. You must be logged in as a sudo admin.', category='error')
            return redirect(url_for('auth.sudo_admin_login'))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view
```

but as soon as i login it pops a success msg using flash and the failure msg that i need admin access

[This is how the output is when the login is successfull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbnlX.png)

Comment: In your sudo_admin_login function I don’t see any code actually logging the user in between the password check and the redirect.

Comment: Hi yep i noticed that and i made a little modifications I am updating it in the question

Comment: I can still see no code actually logging the user in. Have a look at the login_user function in flask-login.

Comment: Hi I have updated the code i was missing a line but i am still getting the same error